# How to run a php file from flex (mxml/actionscript?

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

How do I execute php code which is in another file from my flex application?

The php code I want to execute (nice and simple)

```
 <?php
     echo "My first PHP script!";
 ?>
```

So I want the above to execute. So far I have this in my flex application:

```
 <mx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="C:\Users\blah\blah\blah\src\ItemTableService.php" useProxy="false" method="POST">

    </mx:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:Button label="Submit" click="userRequest"/>
```

So I'm running it locally at the moment. I think there needs to be something on "click-"userRequest.(somethinghere)"/> but not sure what it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

I use the UrlLoader class

```
var url:String="example";
        var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
        urlRequest.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
    //use variables only if yu need them    
var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.something=ex;
        urlRequest.data=variables;
        var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
        urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onError);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Try first your php n your browser see if you can get the correct url, it should be something with localhost or 127.0.0.1   like

```
http://localhost/myscript.php
```

Edit as Josh suggested in the comments you MUST have a web server with PHP support installed and setup.

Comment: Worth noting that PHP requires server-software to run, too. Just having the file on your system is not enough, you'll need to be running Apache or similar (through XAAMP/WAMP/MAMP or similar, generally) to have it run.